# MySQL - Cannot select all subjects and grade using multiple select and join

Tags: mysql, join

My question is about MySQL database. I am doing a student management system, 
and I have stuck with some query, I would like to select grade_point 
grade_name and subject_name. I have four tables wich are related but only one table is out of relationship and I want to use it for comparing mark.

So my expectation is to get all subjects, grade_point, grade_name to display according to student id and exam id.

Here are my tables :

Grade

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|grade_id|grade_name|grade_point|grade_mark_from|grade_mark_up|comment         |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1       |A+        |5          |80             |100          |Very good result|
|2       |A         |4          |70             |79           |Good result     |
|3       |B+        |3.5        |60             |69           |Good result     |
|4       |B         |3          |50             |59           |Good            |
|5       |C         |2          |40             |49           |Good            |
|1       |D         |2.5        |30             |39           |Good            |
|1       |E         |1.5        |1              |33           |No good         |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Exam_Result :

---

```
|resu_id|mark|comment|exam_id|subject_id|student_id|
----------------------------------------------------
|1      |50  | no    |1      |1         |1         |
|2      |30  | no    |1      |1         |2         |
|3      |70  | no    |1      |1         |1         |
|4      |90  | no    |1      |1         |2         |
|5      |60  | no    |1      |1         |1         |
|6      |25  | no    |1      |1         |2         |
```

Subject :

```
 ---------------------------------------
|subject_id|subject_name|using_class_id|
----------------------------------------
|1         |Math        |1             |    
|2         |English     |1             |   
|3         |BL          |2             |   
|4         |Testing     |2             |    
----------------------------------------
```

Table student :

```
 ---------------------------------------
|student_id|student_name|using_class_id|
----------------------------------------
|1         |samphors    |1             |    
|2         |vann        |1             |   
|3         |Dyna        |2             |   
|4         |Khan        |2             |    
----------------------------------------
```

Here is my expectation but is just an example:
[image]

Comment: Your example does not match with your data, this makes it difficult to understand what you want. Also, you talk about four tables but describe three?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`select s.student_name, 
su.subject_name, 
er.mark,
(select gr.grade_mark_up from grade gr where er.mark >= gr.grade_mark_from and er.mark <= gr.grade_mark_up) Highest_Mark,
 (select gr.grade_name from grade gr where er.mark >= gr.grade_mark_from and er.mark <= gr.grade_mark_up) Grade
from students s, exam_result er, subject su
where s.student_id = er.student_id
and er.subject_id = su.subject_id`

The grade_mark_up for  grade "E" is wrong!

Comment: could you explain me more, why it return only first row for hightest_mark and Grade?

Comment: The key is the where condition: "where er.mark >= gr.grade_mark_from and er.mark <= gr.grade_mark_up". I filter the data from grade where the mark of student (er.mark) is in the grade range (gr.grade_mark_from - gr.grade_mark_up). Obviously, if the ranges from table grade are not sequential the subquery don't work. Ok?

Comment: oh, I see . so what is the problem in the query which you have give to me? exactly, it worked but not much at all, there was just a bit problem but I cannot find it . here is the result : http://lh5.ggpht.com/1keiKPDyAIUIl9b3CudR7MFZj7UtpLPDLW95qNIF-rE0Umm9AK29bXn3s1Uly0jQiT2uXTMrO2ltBXBMyGNL

Comment: I think that your problem is the datatype for the .grade_mark_from, grade_mark_up and mark (exam table). The types for those columns must are numeric (int for example). If the datatype are char or varchar the comparison in the where may fail

Comment: Thanks you so much Bdn02. You are a man. here is a final result : http://lh3.ggpht.com/F-9xAh7HZ1U9BOn4Fuhapfrg3vhm6Ga4c6A0r21-ODSSMVGXcqvhCqUA-9rEZOzLNNEwR_rRzoH_oho2LA